# shell character encoding seems to have been altered

Tags: ubuntu, shell, character-encoding

I'm having a problem with my shell on an Ubuntu virtual machine that I `ssh` in to. It was working fine until I output the contents of a JPEG file directly, since then the character encoding seems to have messed up and I've no idea how to fix it. Characters are looking like this:

```
ÆsudoÅ password for rory:
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but the output of `locale` is:

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I've tried rebooting with no effect. Any hints on how to solve?

Comment: BTW, you can use [hexdump](http://google.com/search?q=man+hexdump) (also named hd) to view binary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably in your local terminal rather than the remote system. Try the [`reset`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/reset) command within that terminal (from any system that has it) or close and re-open it.